# Ionic 3 - list not updating after refreshing items from firebase database

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

In my application, I have a searchbar and a list of "tags" below. It is used to let the user add a new tag, with a control filter to check if the word that he's entering already exists in the list. The new tag is added to the database only if it doesn't already exist.
If the word can be added, then a button becomes visible, and after clicking it the new word is pushed to the database. The behavior I'm expecting is that, after adding the word, the list below the searchbar is updated real-time with the new word; instead, after adding it becomes blank, and I have to go back and then go to the page again to see the new list.
Here is the html code for searchbar + list:

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" placeholder="Add tag ... "></ion-searchbar>
<ion-scroll style="width:100%;height:60vh" scrollY="true">
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let tag of tagList">
  <h2> {{ tag.nome }} </h2>
</ion-item>
 </ion-list>
</ion-scroll> 

<button ion-button [disabled]="!isEnabled"(click)="clickedButton()">Add</button>
```

In .ts file this is the code I'm using to save the tag and refresh list:

```
export class NewtagPage {

 public tagList: Array<any>;
 public loadedTagList: Array<any>;



  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public api: Api, 
  public menuCtrl: MenuController, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {


  var ref1 = firebase.database().ref('/tag/'); //get the tags from DB


  //creo la lista di tag
   ref1.once('value', tagList => {
  let tags = [];
  tagList.forEach( poi => {
    tags.push(poi.val());
    return false;
  });

  this.tagList = tags;
  this.loadedTagList = tags;
});

 }



ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.initializeItems();
 }


refreshItems():void{
var ref1 = firebase.database().ref('/tag/'); 
ref1.once('value', tagList => {
     let tags = [];
  tagList.forEach( poi => {
    tags.push(poi.val());
    return false;
  });

  this.tagList = tags;
  this.loadedTagList = tags;
});
}
initializeItems(): void {
 this.tagList = this.loadedTagList;
}

presentToastOk(){

   let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'Tag was added!',
    duration: 2000,
    position: 'top'
  }).present();
  this.initializeItems();
} 

clickedButton(){
  if (this.tagList.length==0){//posso aggiungere il tag
    var tagData = {
      nome: this.textSearch
    }
    var key = firebase.database().ref().child('tag').push().key;
    var updates = {};
    updates['/tag/'+key] = tagData;
    updates['/point_of_interest/'+ this.poi.chiave + '/tags/' + key] = "true";
firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
this.presentToastOk();
this.refreshItems();
this.isEnabled = false;
  } else {
    this.presentToastWrong();

  }
}

//filter function
getItems(searchbar) {
  // Reset items back to all of the items
  this.initializeItems();

  // set q to the value of the searchbar
  var q = searchbar.srcElement.value;
  this.textSearch = q;

  // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
  if (!q) {
    return;
   }


  this.tagList = this.tagList.filter((v) => {
    if(v.nome && q) {
      if (v.nome.toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (this.tagList.length==0){
    this.isEnabled = true;
  } else{
    this.isEnabled = false;
  }
}
}
```

The filter function works perfectly, I've just added it for completeness.
As you can see, the first thing I do when creating the page is getting the tag list for firebase. Then, when the button is clicked, the tag is added to the database, the items are re-initialized through the "presentToastOk" function, and then I refresh the variable that represents the list to be shown on the html.
When I add a new word, the list reappears for a moment and then disappear instantly.
I've used the same method in another project and was working ok. Why it's not working anymore? I've copy-pasted the code just as it was, and now I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know this might be a late response but here's my thoughts:

Most likely the actions are happening asynchronously therefore when you call refreshItems, is very likely that the list stays the same.

A workaround could be using the ion-refresher tag to refresh the list when the user pulls the screen down

For this solution you can check the docs here:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/

However, is this solution is not enough for your app and you see it as a 'feature' only, you could refresh the information by probably adding an Observable

```
this.substription = Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(x => {
      //here there's a delay of 1 sec, you could potentially call your refreshItems() method here.
  });
```

I am using it for a simple clock and it works fine, yet I have not tested this by doing calls to a server for I am not really sure if it'll be a good solution for you, but you could try it and let us know!